# Proposing a definite policy on contest questions

Tags: discussion, policy, contests

There has been a lot of heated debate on this issue lately and as a user, I decided to propose a definite policy on such matters:

The following is my proposed policy

1) When a problem from an ongoing contest is posted *and* someone has pointed us to the source of problems,

we should ask ourselves

a)Is the competition a part of the selection procedure for a particular country's team for the International Mathematical Olympiad?

If (a) is true, we should ask ourselves this

(i)Is the question a problem from a particular contest in the past or a well-known theorem

If so, I propose that the question be kept open.(Olympiad organizers are not supposed to propose well-known problems)[The onus of proof that the question has appeared elsewhere earlier should be on the poster.And we have enough competent people to judge if the problem is a well-known theorem or problem or not]

(ii)The problem is not well-known one at all.

The question should be promptly closed and comments disabled on it till the contest is over

b) If the competition is not part of the selection for the International Mathematical Olympiad, moderators should put up a sign saying:  "This is part of the (name of the contest) competition.Please use your  judgement while posting answers" and the moderators should not try to close the contest.We cannot be responsible for every little contest.

Please use upvotes to vote in favour and downvotes to vote against the proposal.

Edit:This is going to be debate;let us take all viewpoints into consideration as no single viewpoint will likely to be overwhelmingly useful for the site.My attempt is merely an imperfect, but perhaps a necessary one.

Comment: I agree with (ii), but not with the rest, so will neither upvote nor downvote. I agree that we cannot be responsible for every contest, little or not so little. However, for contest questions that have an expiry date, I think that once we are made aware of the facts, there is a need to go beyond providing information.  Please note that the comment is about ongoing contests only, and is not intended to be generalized.

Comment: Just a side remark: whichever policy we adopt, we probably should write it into the FAQ blurb on the main site. (We have the freedom of editing the section under "What kind of questions can I ask here?")

Answer (score 10):

I would like to make a counter-proposal:

If a moderator receives a request to temporarily remove a question from someone, the moderator uses their judgement to determine whether the request is reasonable and comes from a credible source.  If so, they close and delete for the appropriate amount of time.  In cases where it's not obvious that it's a reasonable request, the moderators should err on the side of not closing/deleting questions.  Requests to remove old questions or generally known problems should be denied.  Moderators should not undo decisions like this made by other moderators.

Comment: There are different moderators with different judgment. This proposal will backfire and cause unnecessary heat between the moderators.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Added a sentence at the end to respond to your comment (no one has voted yet).  Honestly I care a lot more about the substantive policy here than about keeping the moderators happy.

Comment: I agree that keeping the moderators happy is somewhat less important than keeping the house in order. However as Gerry's recent thread points out, there has been some "mod wars" (analog to closing-wars or so) recently. This is not good for the moderators **and** bad for the site.

Comment: Certainly that's a problem that should be fixed (and discussed on the other thread, not here), but I don't think we can let bad behavior by moderators change the formation of good policy.  If the response to policy discussions is "we can't enforce that because a moderator will unilaterally over-rule it" then that's a big problem.

Comment: I agree. However I think that it is important to make that addition that you made, just to clarify that mod wars should be avoided on *this* issue as a part of the policy.

Comment: I prefer in the general sense Noah's proposal over the OP. (a) I don't see why the Olympiads should get special treatment (b) while the onus should be on the contest organizers to secure their contest, I consider _patrolling the internet_ and sending out requests to remove contest material a reasonable form of security.

Comment: How answers may be applied should be of no concern to us. MSE's charter is to disseminate mathematical knowledge, not to attempt to enforce motley ethical policies on how such knowledge may be applied. See my comment to zyx's answer.

Comment: Of course how they may be applied should concern us. For most answers there's nothing to worry about. For many of the rest, it's clear that trying to take action would be more harmful than letting them be. These facts do not excuse brushing off the remaining case.

Comment: @Hurkyl Do you similarly believe that librarians should ask how borrowers will apply mathematics before lending them mathematical books?

Comment: Really analogies should be banned in internet discussions, because they result in people arguing about how good the analogy is rather than the point at hand.  Suffice it to say I think "librarian" is a very poor analogy for a site that answers questions rather than providing resources to answer questions.

Comment: Furthermore, many librarians in teaching settings (both high school and college level) do consider part of their job to be preventing cheating and plagiarism.  There are whole books written on this subject (e.g. "Combating student plagiarism: an academic librarian's guide"). I'm pretty confident that if you walk into a library, set your homework on the desk and ask "where can I find the solution manual for my homework" the librarian's response will not be to give you the solution manual to your textbook.

Comment: At all the libraries I can think of that have solution manuals, they serve a high volume of students who come to the desk with a stack of homework and want to use the solution manual. The only access restriction is that the manuals cannot leave the library, because they are in demand.  The plagiarism campaigns are librarians  explaining to students how to cite and locate references. Librarians refusing access to material because of feared plagiarism or cheating is not something I have heard of, but maybe you have some examples in mind.

Comment: @Noah Almost all professional librarians do no restrict access to content in such ways. Please cite an example if you think otherwise, or go have a chat with your local librarian.

Comment: @BillDubuque: There's a difference between restricting access and actively aiding and abetting. I'm sure plenty of librarians see such a difference.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Of course, when the situation warrants it. It's hard to imagine the situation that would warrant it, but when such a situation comes up, it would be foolish to cite one's prior lack of imagination as justification to ignore it. As for the situation at hand, I believe an "answers for everybody, darn the consequences" attitude is appalling. ...

Comment: ... An "I can't imagine a situation where it would be worth considering if and how to restrict answers" is more understandable -- and I *hope* closer to your actual position -- but it is mystifying to push such a position when faced with a concrete issue that people really do believe is worth considering.

Comment: "aiding and abetting" and "cheating" are subjective words.  Can you explain in more objective concrete terms (like question, answer, contest rules, contestant score, ranking of competitors) what the actual problem is that an international web site should restrict its users around this matter?  For the questions that triggered all this, discussion at the contest web site shows what could have been deduced on MSE and is the typical "cheating" situation: the answers were very far from making a difference to any contest outcomes.  But the exposure on MSE did help the contest through publicity.

Comment: @Hurkyl Do your above comments imply that you actually *do* believe that librarians should refuse to lend mathematical books to borrowers whose applications of math do not satisfy certain ethical criteria?

Comment: @Bill: Of course... *when a situation warrants it*. I am honestly surprised that you appear to think lending a book to someone who will use it to cheat on their homework is *good thing*, as opposed to merely advocating a permissive policy due to the danger that a restrictive policy has of false positives, privacy concerns, difficulty of setting criteria for what to restrict, and abuse.

Comment: @Hurkyl if the decision should be outcome-based, which is what you just suggested, then it is not enough to stop the analysis at the magic word *cheating*.  This is an ill defined term and you really mean that a third party will violate rules set by a fourth party.  That may or may not be a bad thing, all things considered.  Reasonable thinkers can disagree on it, and it can depend on many other elements of the situation.  You might think the contests are clean and the answerers dirty, but there are equally good reasons to think the opposite, or have some other opinion.

Comment: @zyx: I want to see reasoned thinkers come to a reasoned conclusion on what policy to continue with, whatever it may be. What I don't want to see is the status quo maintained simply because people got exhausted trying to convince people there's an issue capable of being discussed.

Comment: @Hurkyl That's not what I think. Rather, like librarians, I think that our job is only to disseminate knowledge, not to attempt to police how that knowledge may be used.  I never expected to encounter anyone here who might disagree on the library analog.

Comment: @Bill: I guess to summarize my feelings, it's that there are lots of good reasons to freely spread information around, but when the free spread of information becomes the *end*, rather than the *means*, things have gone too far. I guess we'll just have to disagree on this.

Comment: @Hurkyl It's not clear to me precisely how you think the above remark applies to the matter at hand. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: @Bill: I have gotten the impression from you that the dissemination of information is the *goal*, and that as a matter of principle, one should not attempt to evaluate whether it should cause harm, or if and how to restrict information in order to mitigate that harm. But it is exactly this activity that people are trying to engage in here: if and how to go about restricting questions and answers to contest problems to make things better overall through decreasing harm.

Comment: @Hurkyl What do you think is the "goal" of MSE?

Comment: @Bill: That is a question with may layers. At some level, it is to be a successful website. At another level, the goal is what its users want it to be. As for me personally, I focus on the joys of teaching, and seeing others get it.

Comment: @Hurkyl what is missing is a demonstration that harm is caused and is big enough to overrule the benefit to the asker, answerers and website of the Q+A and of not restricting the Q+A or developing restrictive tendencies in MSE and SE.  The word *cheating* by itself does not demonstrate anything, there isn't necessarily a group of cheated or harmed individuals (and there was none in the case that just occurred, in fact there were beneficiaries only).

Comment: @Bill: I have to ask (even though I am honestly tired of this conversation already), suppose you get an email from a contest organizer asking you to remove a certain question (which by luck has less than 50 views, no comments, votes or answers whatsoever). Would you do that, or would you send them a reply that it is not for you to decide, etc. etc.? Now what if that email came from a rather respected organization, e.g. AMS, would you do the same?

Comment: @Asaf, the MAA and equivalent organizations that run contests operate them with security measures, supervision and time limits for this reason.  Exceptions are for cost savings on components of the overall competition, but there is always a good enough ability to detect violators, or adjust the score calculation if particular problems were posted.  It is not easy to hypothesize a situation where the integrity of a major contest is destroyed by posting problems here, because of all the offline hacks that exist without MSE, and because the core of the contest is supervised.

Comment: @zyx: I see. It still does not answer my question, in particular I wanted Bill's answer to this question. I suppose you're not Bill... :-)

Comment: @Asaf, what will happen in the situations you propose is that MAA will email the Stack Exchange Corporation with a copyright notice or a request to remove material.  It is possible that SE would sell out the users' interests such as freedom of discussion in exchange for the corporate interest of good relations with prestigious organizations (SE advertises the partnership with AMS on TeX/Mathjax, and its relation with the "math community" at Math Overflow).  Or decide for the users what their interests are, in some other way. Moderators would not play much role in the decision.

Comment: @Asaf Are your proposing some sort of contest policy where not all contests are equal, and only contests with enough "prestige" deserve to have their questions locked or deleted? That's yet another can of worms that would be unwise to open here. These matters are orthogonal to the charter of MSE. Attempting to address them here will only lead to no good, possibly alienating many members. Most of our users come here to discuss mathematics, not to get thrust into the middle of heated arguments on ethical matters that have absolutely nothing to do with the charter of MSE.

Comment: @Bill: No... I asked what would you do if you would have received such email. Once again you avoid the *real* question and address the less important detail. What would you have told the organizer of **any** contest that have sent you an email requesting for a question to be closed/deleted/locked? For simplicity sakes, assume the question has extremely low exposure and no response from the community.

Comment: @Asaf The question is not relevant since, as I stated *numerous* times, these matters are beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: @Bill: I don't care if the question is relevant, instead of a straightforward answer we seem to waltz around for several comments which you will later use to claim that this is going off topic, and in later occasions use against me with "you do this all the time" sort of comebacks... The question itself **is** relevant because as I stated *numerous* times, this site must not ignore *all* other mathematical bodies in the world.

Comment: @Asaf, your pestering is off topic and reads like an attack or an attempt to manipulate the discussion.  I don't think Bill should answer it.  If you have a serious question as to what *the moderators* would do then poll all of them (somewhere else).  They have different stances and who knows which one will get the call and do what, in case of a message from AMS.  If you are trying to express *your* opinion on what should happen in this situation, you don't need Bill's help for that.  As for what Bill thinks, let him communicate that, and if your curiosity is not satisfied, that is OK.

Comment: @zyx: Since Bill is the main antagonist in *most* cases, and its seems that he is also an extreme separatist I wanted to hear *his* opinion. Since I don't really go well with Bill, I always prefer to have open communications with him. I *do* think it is relevant to this subject. Since you are not a moderator and he *is* a moderator, furthermore he undid actions taken by *other* moderators, I wanted to hear his answer to this question.

Comment: @Asaf I already gave you the answer. These matters are beyond the scope of this site. That applies to *all* contests.

Comment: @Asaf: then open a new question or answer for your investigation.  If this is a real question on site administration, we need to hear from all the moderators.  At least two other moderators have made statements that sound to me like they might do the same as Bill D, only for different reasons.  One says it is not reasonable to have a special policy and another is against imposing his preferences when there is no consensus.  Your curiosity, or the belief that you can prove an unreasonable ultra-extremism through hypothetical thought experiments, is not a reason to drag everyone else along.

Comment: @zyx: What is the point of investigating whether harm is caused when people like yourself still reject the idea that cheating *can* be harmful, or Bill who considers whatever harm done as being completely irrelevant?

Comment: @Hurkyl: I did not "reject the idea that cheating can be harmful".  I did ask you, or whoever believes that there is a problem requiring a reduction in what can be posted and communicated on the site, to provide a more convincing cost-benefit analysis than the magic word *cheating*.  Or to discuss it in some more specific way than writing an 8-letter word and demanding reform.  It is not a hypothetical concern; in the case that started these conversations there was no harm and some benefit.

Comment: @zyx: There clearly was *some* harm done. The integrity of the competition was damaged at least slightly, even if you don't place value on such things. If you won't even admit that, then *surely* you'll admit the reputation of the site has been damaged enough to cause some people to be less willing to contribute, or even to drive some away entirely, and has caused distress to the community here? (I'm tempted to challenge you on the assertion that the OMO has *benefited* from the incident, but I think that would be too much of a diversion from the topic)

Comment: The integrity and prestige of (previously obscure) OMO was not harmed, it *increased* as a result of the exposure. I'd argue this was true before it reached the meta and Speyer's blog, and it is definitely true afterward. The organizers' public response also improved the status of the contest. Anything and everything could be claimed about the "reputation of the site".  Maybe the same people who oppose contest problems on the site were happy that there was a rapid ID of the contest, seven threads on meta, and punitive downvotes.  Or the libertarians are happy it is being thrashed out on meta.

Comment: @zyx: One can imagine all sorts of things about the reputation of the site, but we have cold, hard evidence of the things I mentioned: Yemon Choi's comment in this question, the meta question http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6209/request-for-my-id-to-be-deleted, and the general tone of the overall issue that has subsequently been prompted. Also, please clarify whether you really mean "no harm was done", or simply "I believe the good has outweighed the harm". If the former, then please explain. If the latter, then please stop denying that harm has been done.

Comment: @Hurkyl Our primary concern should be with *this* site, not random external sites. Forcing an externally-composed code of ethics onto members of this site will cause much harm to *this* site. Please do not lose sight of that.

Comment: @Hurkyl Please *do not* attempt to put words into my mouth. I stated that the policing of cheating on external sites is beyond the scope of this site. I never said anything like "I consider whatever harm done as being completely irrelevant". Do not expect me to reply to any further of your comments if you continue to engage in unscrupulous oratorical tactics.

Comment: @Bill: But we're discussing the issue of whether this site should police cheating that occurs on *this* site. Also, only the latter half of that phrase was aimed at you, and is based on comments like: "How answers may be applied should be of no concern to us." "These matters are beyond the scope of this site." "We should not cripple our site based on matters having nothing to do with us." "This is not our problem." Also, phrases like "I think that our job is only to disseminate knowledge, not to attempt to police how that knowledge may be used.", if I assume it's meant to apply to this issue.

Comment: I'm sorry if I've misinterpreted these phrases, but after our discussion last night, you had thoroughly convinced me that you think we should be completely unconcerned of any effects that answers or other activity on this site may or may not have elsewhere. (Though, as I mention to zyx above, such things do ultimately have effects on this site itself through things like it's reputation)

Comment: @Hurkyl If you consider that giant leap (from what I said to what you claim I said) to be a valid logical inference, then I'm afraid our views of logic and/or debating ethics are so far apart that there is little point in continuing.

Comment: 2 weeks ago, OMO was an obscure math contest organized by high school students in their spare time. It just got roughly a thousand eyeballs from a very desirable (for a contest) audience. It is being mentioned, on a high-rank website and a leading math blog, in the same breath as larger, prestigious and established contests such as USAMTS and national IMO selections.  The top 10 winners list, which is the only visible output of the contest, is not affected whatsoever, and the value for *any* team of being at *any* documented rank in OMO (possibly one lower due to MSE answers) has skyrocketed.

Comment: In addition the perceived integrity of the contest is higher now that, through inspection of the quality of the problems, and their sensible public statement about the MSE postings, the organizers are looking much more credible.  Previously nobody knew that this wasn't a joke contest or a way to fluff the resumes of their math friends.  It seems now that they did a great job and have impressed many people with the quality of problems, maturity and ability to handle issues. This whole episode is a HUGE WIN for those you call victims of "cheating".  I doubt they would disagree. Ask them!

Comment: @zyx: Great. On the assumption that is true, so what? I assume you're responding to my request that you explain why you think no harm was done, and you haven't done that. You talk about doing a cost-benefit analysis, but that requires actually acknowledging the costs! When arguing that a situation is a net positive, it is dishonest to pretend the negatives don't exist.

Comment: Also, one should ask: what bearing does this actually have on the issue at hand? Is any benefit they gained really the product of an MSE policy to allow answers to contest questions? Or is it instead entirely the result of members of their community calling MSE out on the issue, along with the way their organizers responded to the situation? MSE is not a hero uplifting the little man in this story.

Comment: @Hurkyl, I am saying that as far as OMO organizers and participants are concerned, literally nobody was harmed.  You could argue that the organizers were "harmed" by spending a certain amount of time writing a message for the Internet (that made them look good!), or that I am harmed by aging some number of minutes while reading your argumentative comments, or other ancillary effects.  But your claim was of harm to the "integrity of the contest", and unless you can explain specifically where such harm occurred and to whom, that part of the question (as you formulated it) appears to be settled.

Comment: As I said, there was arguably a benefit to the contest and its credibility prior to the meta involvement, from exposure and for other reasons that I didn't detail in 500char comments. It is unarguably true (and you haven't disputed it in any concrete way) that the final result was positive, for the contest and for every individual involved in OMO.  If you want to analyze the result of MSE policy you would have to compare to an alterna-MSE that is more restricted and the tangible and intangible losses of that, first for MSE itself and secondarily for its ability to affect other entities.

Comment: I have not attempted to dispute that assertion, nor would I have reason to in the course of the point I'm making. My primary intent in this sub-thread of discussion is simply to get you to admit that cheating is generally a bad thing for a competition (or to provide a reasonable reason why you think otherwise). Now, I'm also inclined to take issue with the apparent suggestion that it's actually a good thing for MSE to go around helping people cheat in competitions because it gives their community a chance to earn prestige by taking us to task on it.

Comment: Not disputing the demonstrated statement that "[for] the contest and its credibility ... it is unarguably true that the final result was positive ... and for every individual involved" appears to be a complete abandonment of your earlier assertion that "There clearly was some harm done ... the integrity of the competition was damaged at least slightly, even if you don't place value on such things".  I don't have time to answer the other stuff before the weekend, and it would be better if you opened a question or answer for any further analyses, but I thought I'd mention that slight detail.

Comment: @zyx: $x+y > 0$ does not contradict $x < 0$.

Answer (score 6):

I propose we do nothing special for contest problems, and treat them the same as other questions.

Comment: Here here! (Padding to satisfy minimum comment length.)

Answer (score 0):

I posted this at the end of a long chain of comments, but perhaps it can be considered a proposal.

1. FAQ has an item informing online contest organizers that they can (if they choose to) ask an MSE moderator to post their contest problems on MSE in a locked form. When doing so, the organizers should specify the contest period, which is indicated in the post.
2. The questions are unlocked at the specified date. MSE users can then post their solutions and vote for the best one, as is usually done.
3. If another MSE user posts one of these contest questions, it is closed as a duplicate, which is already done on a regular basis. A duplicate is not necessarily a verbatim copy. The MSE users have sufficient experience deciding whether Question X should be closed as a duplicate of Question Y, and they can apply the same practice here.

Comment: I don't agree. Questions should be *real* questions posed by users genuinely interested in learning the mathematics required for their solution. They should not be locked placeholders posted only for the purpose of preventing variations on these questions from being asked here. Again, I emphasize that difficulties posed by the creation of online competitions should be of no concern to this site. This site has *nothing* to do with external matters such as online competitions.

Comment: @BillDubuque The second sentence is not true as stated. SE allows encyclopedia-type questions, by posting which the OP does not necessarily seek new knowledge. I did not learn anything new by posting [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159659/which-sets-are-removable-for-holomorphic-functions), for example.

Comment: Encyclopedia postings, and virtually every other use of the duplicate questions rubric, allow for posting new answers under at least one version of the question.  This is not true under the preventive locking, which is a huge difference and a complete reversal of the existing SE philosophy on duplicates (such as to prevent redundancy, increase the efficiency for users, reduce unwanted material instead of adding it as this proposal would do).  Additional criticisms of preventive locking are at the end of the comment trail under my answer, where LVK had originally made the proposal.

Comment: @LVK I'm sure you knew what my point was, so there is no need to quibble over tangential technicalities.

Answer (score -1):

I think that any attempt to patrol contest problems here (vs action by the contest organizers, before and after they are notified) will run into endless difficulties.

Deletion helps those who post with the intention of cheating on a contest. They may get some useful answers, and are auto-notified of replies, but other contestants are kept in the dark.

Locking contest problem P, but not functionally similar questions such as reference-requests, generalizations, specializations, reductions, or sub-problems based on P, is a fig leaf that allows the more moralistically inclined users of the site to claim concern for the contests while allowing open cheating in all the indirect ways.  For some forms of indirection there will be serious differences of opinion as to whether it is good or bad in relation to a contest (such as asking where to find problems similar to $P_1$, methods useful for $P_2$, or practice problems helpful to those wanting to solve $P_3$).

Restricting in any way the discussion of questions that are "similar" to open contest problems, or could potentially disrupt the contests if applied in the obvious way, is a serious form of censorship to the site.  A cure much worse than the disease.

Comment: It would be helpful if the downvoters could state their alternative positions/preferences on restriction of questions that are not literally on the contest, but similar or related in the ways listed in the answer.  Generalize or specialize the problem, mask it by minor variations, ask for references, the tricks are numerous and obvious.

Comment: My point of view is that it's not M.SE's problem to root out all endless variations of contest and exam problems, but that when problematic questions are pointed out to M.SE then we should behave like good citizens of the mathematical community and close the questions.

Comment: @Noah, I don't dispute that many mathematicians think they are part of a "mathematical community", but this is to some extent an internal illusion (the social aggregate of mathematicians lacks basic defining attributes of a community). Even if that community ideal were absolutely real, the M.SE community is not the mathematical one but an enormously larger, ideologically amorphous, set of users of math web sites.  I don't think that they would necessarily appreciate a tiny subset assuming rhetorical control over the values and interests of the totality.

Comment: Hear, hear! I think it is best that we operate with the same principles as do librarians. We disseminate knowledge, but we are in no position to control how that knowledge may be used, nor should we be. It would be very dangerous to admit ethical arguments into our topicality policy, else we expose MSE to all sorts of analogous ethical arguments on applications of answers, e.g. "please delete this post because the author is using such mathematics to build weapons of mass destruction, or stem cell research, or cryptography for censorship in oppressive regimes", etc.

Comment: Also (again in reply to @Noah), I don't understand what kind of good citizenship, in whatever form of community, includes closing the actual contest questions but not the subtle and not-so-subtle variants.  The reasons given for close/lock/delete of the contest questions do not pertain to the intent of the OP's (who might not know about the contest), but the likely potential effect on the contest.  The effect is the same for the variant questions, especially if they are posted by would-be cheaters, or if the other contestants read MSE, or a comment identifies the related contest and problem #.

Comment: @zyx: As I wrote in some other thread. I hope to have a future in the academy. I would not like my name to be linked to a site which has a nefarious reputation for cheating. Homework questions are quite the grayscale, and I have a very strong opinion where I stand on this scale. I can testify that the good users on this site closed and deleted home-exam questions, once those were identified as such. I honestly feel that if MSE chooses to ignore the outside world on those issues, then it is no longer a community I should feel comfortable in, and I am sure that I am not the only one.

Comment: @Asaf, this is not a site specific to members of academia, who are a small if not tiny segment of the users.  In any case, I still do not see any explanation from anyone who wants closure of the contest/journal/homework/exam problems, of what this should imply for the variants of those problems.  If they are OK, you are sanctioning open, nefarious, evil, world-ending, etc cheating under a fig leaf.  If they are subject to restriction, the site is under significant censorship.  How do you propose to consistently deal with that problem?

Comment: @zyx: Of course it's not. However I do believe that a majority of the high rep. users are involved in the academia somehow. I also recall not too long ago that the fact that one expert or another were interested in some questions suddenly made them *extremely* legitimate. So I am wondering, is the fact that there are people involved in the academia amongst the hardcore users group a *good* thing, or do the community only like that as a rubber stamp when needed?

Comment: @Asaf, the relative value of academic and non-academic posters is off-topic and does not answer the question being posed here.

Comment: @zyx: Why did you bring it up, then?

Comment: @Asaf, if you re-read the comments above you will see that I did not say anything about the comparative value of academic and non-academic posters.  I did ask, but did not receive an answer, about how the variants of the contest/journal/homework/examination problem would be dealt with according to the academic good citizen values, and am genuine interested in any answers you or others may have.  It is particularly relevant in the case where the solid citizens prevail in setting a policy.

Comment: @zyx: While most courses do grade homework assignments, in my view the *main* point behind these exercises is to get used to applying definitions and getting used to a certain settings. I see no harm, and rather a good deal of help, to sit and explain something to someone in full. Because of this I don't think that every homework problem deserves closure. Exams, on the other hand are meant to actually measure how well you did your homework and understood the material on your own -- and for that they should be closed. Contests are meant for an individual or a particular team [cont.]

Comment: [...] to solve on their own and show how creative and capable they are. For this I also believe that solving contest problems for others is wrong. The journal problems is something that I have yet to give much thought about, so I will refrain from taking a stand at this point. All in all **my personal** view is that while we should not go extremely out of our way to deal with contest questions, we *should* - nay **must** - play along with other communities on the internet, and otherwise. Claiming that we have no responsibility towards anyone whatsoever is shooting aimlessly at our own feet.

Comment: That explains what everyone knows, which is that exams and contests are considered *serious business* in some circles.  We all know that, and it wasn't the question.  For the Nth time, I am asking, taking it as a given that exams/contests are sacred, how does somebody who believes they are sacred propose to deal with the unholy variations derived from the holy exam/contest problems?  Generalizations, specializations, reference requests, and the rest.

Comment: I don't have a good idea *how* to deal with them. I also have no idea how to deal with the Iranian situation, I do know that starting a nuclear war is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I think a more correct nuclear-ish war analogy is, after a lot of promotional rhetoric, to build a laser defense system that can shoot down any missile in the national colors of Iran, any military ship flying the Iranian national flag, any airplane using the open channel Iranian radio frequencies, etc.  The security implications of this are predictable.  (@Asaf)

Comment: @zyx Regarding variants: this is not much different from the current situation where MSE users have to decide whether Question X should be closed as a duplicate of Question Y. There is no bright line there either. The same criteria used now for duplicates could apply to the contest questions. A question could be closed if it can be considered a duplicate of a contest problem. This would actually be straightforward if the contest organizers, with the help of moderators, posted their contest questions here in locked form -- to be unlocked, discussed and solved at a specified date.

Comment: @LVK, that is clever but basically an abuse and a hijacking of the "close duplicate questions" element of the Stackexchange interface.  It is an unequivocal assumption of the process that duplicative questions can be closed only when *at least one version is open for new answers*.  There are few, if any, subjects for which the locked-duplicate function is used as a kludge to explicitly prevent discussion, and on a math site it is an abuse.  I believe it may have been done for a very small number of topics here, and was a terrible mistake in each case.

Comment: (continuing).  It also encourages cheaters to post *multiple* versions of a question, maybe under different user names, with different degrees of duplication, so I have serious doubts whether it can solve the problem in the way you propose.

Comment: @zyx I think that *at least one version is open for new answers [to be posted at a specified date]* is not that far from being open now. I regularly prepare answers in a different application, and post them on MSE later; what's the big deal if I have to wait? Spammers can spam, of course; that's nothing new.

Comment: @LVK,  encouraging spam of a kind that will involve disputes, votes, fine-grained moderator judgements between similar questions, dueling hard-line and permissive factions each time the matter arises, repetitive questions where really only one answer is sought, and an inflation of the volume of undesired material, is very different from the ordinary off-topic spam that is handled easily and automatically.  I would say it is something new.

Comment: @LVK, regarding *open for new answers [later]*, this is even more similar to a question *having been deleted*.  Posting later can always be done, there is no new capability added by the preventive locking.  It is clearly worse than deletion, since it relies on the same degree of user/moderator activity, but introduces a new concept of *unanswerable questions* hitting the front page.  In the frequent case of contest questions that repeat earlier questions on the site, it will cause conflicts with the current philosophy and practice of duplicate questions.

Comment: What the preventive locking really is most similar to, is *free advertising on the front page of the Q&A space for specially favored contests*. One ad for each question they have, for as long as the contest operates (several weeks at a time, in some cases), and possibly over-riding the freedom to discuss earlier questions on the site that suddenly become duplicates of the contest matter.

Comment: @zyx If a question put forward by contest organizers for inclusion in MSE turns out to already exist on MSE, then no action is needed. Organizers will have to bear the consequence of their using an un-original contest problem. My proposal concerned only the situation when contest problems are original -- in which case their authors should have a say in how they are distributed online, in accordance with copyright laws.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, and clarifying that it is a proposal. The fact remains that this type of arrangement is objectively worse than an auto-deletion, in addition to the other problems of favoritism, multiplying the unwanted postings, and not serving the intended purpose (protecting the contests) without greatly expanding the notion of "duplicate" to include anything that usefully relates to a sub-problem, a variant problem, a reference-request, etc. Also, if closing as duplicate rests on user judgment there can be open-close cycles with accompanying disputes on meta. (@LVK)

Comment: @LVK Why do you think that mathematical problems can be copyrighted?

Comment: @BillDubuque: I am pretty sure under present copyright laws, _specific statements_ of mathematical problems can be copyrighted, just like everything else that is written. And like mostly everything else, paraphrasing goes a long way toward preventing, strictly speaking, copyright infringement.

Comment: The "mathematical community" is much larger than just academic mathematicians.  It includes summer programs, AoPS, m.SE, high school math teachers, etc.  People who care about mathematics and are involved in promoting mathematics.  If someone is putting a bunch of effort into running a competition, the least we can do is help them out in very minor ways to avoid our accidentally or purposefully abetting cheating.  It's a question of simple decency and niceness to people who put a lot of effort into mathematics, and who we'd expect to help us out in the future if we made a reasonable request.

Comment: @Willie A friend who knows much about copyright law (and mathematics) does not agree that mathematical problems can be copyrighted.

Comment: @Bill: does he say so about "specific statements" or just the (mathematical) content of mathematical problems themselves? The latter is likely covered by [Feist v Rural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feist_v._Rural) as compendium of information cannot be copyrightable by itself (a mathematical formula is not copyrightable). But the specific phrasing of a mathematical problem (e.g. a word problem setting up a scenario to which mathematics is applied) should be able to pass the _threshold of originality_ test.

Comment: @Bill: for example, the Mathematical Association of America quite clearly believes that [the USAMO exam questions are copyrighted](http://amc.maa.org/a-activities/a7-problems/problemUSAMO-IMOarchive.shtml).

Comment: @Willie I don't recall the details (it was from a conversation many years ago). However, it is a moot point since I doubt anyone would ever be foolish enough to attempt to do so.

Comment: @WIllie Re: claimed USAMO copyright. Suppose someone collected together a compilation of Best of MSE problems and claimed copyright on that. Would you respect that claim?

Comment: @Willie, that MAA page says only that "the USAMO exams" are copyrighted.  The legal questions here include whether posting an individual question is exempted under Fair Use, whether the exemption is affected by the contest being in progress, and if it is fair use then what quantity of posted snippets constitute unfair use.  Modifications of the problems are outside the realm of copyright, which returns us to the matter of variant problems being posted.

Comment: @Bill: the two situations are clearly not even remotely similar. All USAMO problems are supposed to be original (as in, not having been asked in that form before). Please stop using false analogies.

Comment: @Zyx: My comments are only meant to address [Bill's question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6229/proposing-a-definite-policy-on-contest-questions/6236#comment21840_6236), and not fair use etc., which  should be discussed if issues arise from excerpting copyrighted material. About _that_ I make no claims (since _I_ can't discern a consistent rubric in the US court decisions). As to modifications: that is why I [made a passing remark about paraphrasing](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6229/proposing-a-definite-policy-on-contest-questions/6236#comment21843_6236).

Comment: @Willie How do you define "original"? Most contest problems are what we would call abstract duplicates. In any case this is a moot point, since the only possibly copyrightable aspect - the "specific statement" - is easily avoided by simply rephrasing the problem in one of infinitely many variations. In fact any competent student could easily rephrase a problem to make the relationship with the original quite obscure (esp. to a mathematical layperson such as most judges).

Comment: @Bill: Glad to see you've come to the same conclusion [I did 6 hours ago](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6229/proposing-a-definite-policy-on-contest-questions/6236#comment21843_6236). Cheers. `:-)`

Comment: @Willie I came to that conclusion long before this site existed. But how is that relevant? In any case, I'm glad that we agree on that point, since, in this thread, the issue of copyright is a red herring. Hopefully those who wish to discuss it further will open a new thread, to avoid further distraction here.

Comment: @mt_: I disagree as a factual matter about how easy it is to cheat on difficult math contests and exams.  There are very few people who are able to answer such questions, most contestants don't know many such people, and most people who can answer hard math questions *won't help people cheat*.  I really don't know of many places other than m.SE that have a critical mass of people who are very good at math and have a desire to help people cheat on math contests.

Comment: @Noah, I haven't noticed this critical mass of contest enemies. Could you elaborate? Is there any indication that adding the ongoing-contest information to a question will not suffice?  The "cheating sensitized" users will concentrate their wrath on anyone who dares answer, so the reputation system is not an incentive, and the problems usually are not terribly new or interesting (for those who know well how to solve them).  Where are all these potential contest killers you speak of?

Comment: Users here have stated repeatedly that in their opinion contest problems asked at m.SE should be answered the same way as other questions, and these comments often get several upvotes. There seems to be a nontrivial contingency here for the point of view that even if a question is known to be a contest problem it should still be answered.

Comment: @Noah, the point of view expressed in many forms by many users has been only that the *option to answer* should be the same for all questions, and not restricted based on a special status for contest, exam, or homework.  It's pretty clear, isn't it, that as in more general questions of "free speech", fighting to the last pixel for your right to answer contest questions has no implications about the fighter's interest in performing or supporting that type of speech.  It is interesting and possibly sad that this has to be explained to a group of professors and PhDs.

Comment: @Noah Please do not make false accusations such as claiming that some MSE members "have a desire to help people cheat on math problems." There are many very persuasive arguments here against locking or deleting contest problems. None of them have anything to do with helping people cheat. It is worth emphasis that there are many excellent teachers who believe that competitions do more harm than good pedagogically. Perhaps it may not be well-known to competition-lovers that such folks do exist. They do, in abundance (in my experience).

Comment: @BillDubuque can correct me if I'm wrong, and I hope I am, but my understanding is that he thinks contest and exam questions should be treated like all other questions and given full and complete answers.

Comment: @Noah But the professed reasons for treating all questions equally have absolutely nothing to do with "helping people cheat." That questions answered here can be used to cheat, build bombs, suppress free speech, etc. is an external matter beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Crossed posts there (by 4 seconds), my comment was in direct response to zyx's comment, not Bill's comment.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Do I understand correctly that in your opinion if someone asks a question from an exam or contest and you know this fact, your opinion is that you should answer the question.  But that you want to clarify that although you're in favor of knowingly helping someone cheat, your goal in doing so isn't to help them cheat.

Comment: @Noah As I've stated *many* times here, I believe that any ethical matters having to do with answers posed here are completely beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Treating contest questions like all others does not mean "giving them full and complete answers", or any particular type of answer.  Please stop repeating that, it is misleading and a form of politics we don't need here. Equal means giving any potential answerers the freedom to decide what to post and when to post it, including full and complete immediate answers if some want to give them.  Others will not reply, or provide a hint, or weigh some combination of positive and negative factors in choosing what to do.  What is not clear is why *your* weights should be decisive for *them*.

Comment: Y'all are free to give lengthy answers and make yourselves feel either clever or munificent; I personally dislike freeloading when it comes to academic challenges. This attitude, if not the issue of contest questions, is one reason I've essentially given up on MSE

Comment: @Noah, your questions to Bill are so loaded that I'm surprised he responds.  If you set aside for a moment the sacred concepts about *cheating* and frame the question in some other terms, such as effects of answering (on the OP, on the site, on the contest, on the world, the national debt, or anything else of interest) then the merits of answering can look quite different from the approach in which one assumes it is "cheating" and runs in horror.   I think the previously tiny and obscure OMO contest did very well from having its problems posted and debated here.

Comment: @Noah Let's consider an analogous question. Suppose your town high-school designed an online math competition. Suppose that the organizer discovered that some of the problems have answers given in popular books owned by many of the local libraries. Do you think it would be appropriate for the organizer to request that the libraries restrict access to those books for the week-long duration of the contest, and to ask for the list of users who have already borrowed the book? I can tell you without a doubt that no competent librarian would do so. Nor should we do the analogous thing here.

Comment: @BillDubuque: If a question were already on m.SE before the contest, then indeed we should leave the answer up. There's a huge difference between information that's already available and *made-to-order solutions given to someone trying to cheat*.

Comment: @Noah So does that mean that you *do* think that libraries should restrict access to such books and that they should reveal the list of users who borrowed them upon request?

Comment: @Noah, the "trying to cheat" is something you imposed on the situation. It's not something derivable from MSE visible information. When someone posts here what we know (let's say) is that there is a question and a contest it came from.  If the poster is a contestant at all, which is not always true, he/she can be "trying to ..." do any number of things that do violate the rules of the contest, but do not necessarily mean a disruption of the sacred meritocratic order, damage to the contest, or whatever else it is that bothers you about cheating.

Comment: No, it means I don't think the library *should write a new book at the request of someone competing in the competition*. As I said, existing old questions like existing old books should stay up.

Comment: @Noah But most of the answers on MSE do already exist in books in one form or another. Only a small percentage of the content on MSE is novel. So the answers here do not correspond to writing new books (and even if they did, that is not relevant).

Comment: @YemonChoi Will you stop using the internet too, because it too can be used for so many nefarious purposes?

Comment: @BillDubuque I have stopped using certain other corners of the internet because they seem to have a consensus, or dominant voices, espousing things I find objectionable. I don't find myself needing to *use* MSE and I find increasingly that I don't want to *contribute*

Comment: [deleted earlier attempt at levity, in deference to @NoahSnyder's observation that hyperbole may be inflammatory]

Comment: @Yemon In every large general-level math forum there are always differences of opinions on subjective matters. It's the nature of the beast.

Comment: @BillDubuque, why don't you put your opinion as an answer?That way upvotes and downvotes will tell you whether people like them or not.

Comment: In fact ,you oppose every opinion contrary to what you think and you have refused to post your opinion as an answer.

Comment: @user41685, there is a new and votable one line answer to  "treat all questions the same".

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to downvote it.

Comment: @user41685  A comment there would serve the same purpose.  All the voting is basically a stalemate so it will not make a big difference in convincing anybody.

Comment: @user41685 These issues were already voted on in a thread last month. The highest voted answer was that questions of this sort should receive no special treatment except notifying the organizers.

Comment: Those earlier vote numbers, and links to analogous votes on (not) regulating homework answers, can be found here  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/contest-questions-on-math-se#comment21827_4005

Answer (score -3):

[ Many edits and additions, see end of posting. ]

I would like to point out that there are hacks that make it impossible for locking to prevent the use of MSE to obtain answers.  For this answer, the word *saboteur* is adapted from some of the earlier conversation, where it was claimed that answering live contest questions is sabotage, but the term *answerer* could be used instead.

Askers can include contact information and other clues in their user profile. *Send warez to (...) @ email.com* .  Saboteurs can search for recent closed or locked questions under the (contest-math) tag, look through the asker profiles, and supply solutions.

Questions can include invitations to discussion of the same problems on other sites. *I saw this interesting problem on (link to unmoderated contest problem BBS)*.  Users who want to promote these sites can do it with links in questions, answers and comments.  This can be done persistently but on topic and within MSE posting guidelines, to grow a community of contest solvers in addition to getting information about particular problems.  The growth does not have to come only from the immediate needs of a current contest, and no conspiracy is required.

Saboteur solvers can include contact information in their profile and clues in their answers. *I like to discuss contest problems, hit me up at (...)*.  Over time this would circumvent a deletion policy, no matter how extensive, by using MSE as a meeting and advertising place for a population that does its Q + A elsewhere.  Frequent users would learn who to call when they need help that is restricted.   If the askers and solvers can find their community using MSE it doesn't matter so much if it is done through question-answer or some other means.

This is, at the moment, minor or nonexistent compared to the more traditional ways of gaming unsupervised competitions, such as spending ridiculous amounts of time (which is within the rules), forming a large team of solvers, outsourcing the work to hired guns, or having a giant library of books with problems and solutions.  But it illustrates the futility of trying to restrict the answers here.

Earlier, Noah Snyder had speculated that there is a "critical mass" of users here who actively desire the solution of active contest problems, or despise math competitions, or for whatever reason would eagerly sabotage the contests.  I don't think that is correct, but if there is no large saboteur population here at present, it is possible that it would grow in response to measures taken to restrict contest discussion.  Or not, but it is a possibility to consider.

In response to the comments, I rewrote most of this answer, but would also like to underline the point that there is nothing *conspiratorial* here.  No coordinated planning or communication is necessary.  Individuals can act alone and in a short time deliberately or spontaneously organize a community.  The volume and exposure of MSE would make that possible and no amount of locking and deletion policies can control it.

Comment: I don't know if you've been watching too much X-Files or too many times Conspiracy Theory with Mel Gibson. Either choice is a decent way to pass time, but this post just seems... overly conspiring. Are there ninjas on the lawn trying to kill us? :-)

Comment: @Asaf, some might say the same about obsessing whether somebody somewhere is *cheating*.  If you don't think the hacking is likely, or you believe that the potential saboteur population is small (as I said to Noah when he proposed it as an important element of the cheating discussion), then that would also suggest the cheating problem is minor or imaginary.

Comment: I think that *everyone* that partook in the comments discussion on your previous answer (you, me, Bill, Willie, Noah, Yemon, **everyone**) should *clear their cache*, by drinking or whatever. You have *any* idea how insane you people sound?? This is just madness. It is not long before someone connects the Israeli-Iranian crisis to this problem, or even WW-II (with respect to Godwin's law...). Seriously guys, take a day off. Take a break. Take a night to relax. Then read this page again...

Comment: It's weird how you claim that mathematicians don't form a community in a real sense, but contest saboteurs who act alone would spontaneously form a community. Needless to say, I think that what you wrote here is an extremely far fetched situation. *Especially* if the saboteurs work alone.

Comment: The saboteurs would form even less of a community (the kind that has trust, reciprocity, acquaintance, kinship, etc) than mathematicians. You could call it a group, a collection, a community, a ring, an underground, or something else.  The saboteurs only need to be a significant number of users on an unmoderated forum, it does not have to be devoted to contest analysis.  And there can be a large number of non saboteurs who are not for or against the contests, but just use the forum.  This all can develop, and maybe has already, with nobody knowing or caring about others who do the same.

Comment: Yes. And The Blackadder is a true story of British history.

Comment: We are talking about people doing things openly that are legal and generally positive (answering math questions). Setting up another site can be as simple as a matter of taste, such as preference for a low tech unmoderated math forum on Yahoo or Google groups, versus glitzy but moderated Mathjax on MSE. Advertising one site on another, using non-spam, unremovable messages is really not such a big deal. Words like "conspiracy" are hard to apply in a totally open environment where everything happens in the sunlight. This is straightforward stuff, not sci-fi.

Comment: Derivation of the word *saboteur* added at beginning of answer, to avoid silly issues about conspiracy.